# How to extract structured information from a text string?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining, natural-language

I have a text string containing unstructured data and I would like to analyze it in order to extract structured information. In particular, this text string specifies when a service is operational (the days and the hours). This text string may be written in different ways:

- a list containing one or more day names;
- hours may be written next to the names of the days to which they refer;
- the string may contain one or more range of days (each range of days could have a certain range of hours);
- the name of the days may not be present, and in this case it could be replaced by "every day" or the words "workdays" or by "holidays";
- etc..

What approach could I use to be able to extract structured information from such a text string? Are there specific algorithms to achieve this purpose? Should I use a classifier (artificial neural networks, random forests, etc.)?

Comment: Did you consider to use [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) ?

Answer (score 1):

> What approach could I use to be able to extract structured information from such a text string?

The task corresponds to named-entity recognition + relation extraction. Two main choices:

- Unsupervised, which in your case  most likely mean defining regular expressions and a bunch of heuristic ( e.g., hours directly succeeds days to reach that refer to )
- Supervised

You can mix both choices, e.g. perform the named-entity recognition supervisedly, and  relation extraction unsupervisedly.

From the examples you gave, I'd go unsupervisedly at first.